# Oracle ODBC driver, invalid access to memory location

Tags: oracle

Sharing as I only found this by luck and it's far from intuitive

I got this message when I opened the ODBC Data Source Administrator and clicked Add -> Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit

"invalid access to memory location"

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was that the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files hadn't been setup in the product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin folder, there was just the default sqlnet.ora file. As soon as these were added it worked